# C - creating a struct with input-dependent number of arrays

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I’m wondering if anyone could provide any advice on storing “class slices” of values? I.e., for a table of values (see below for example), I want to be able to store, for each row, an array of the values that corresponds to each class. I have already sorted the table by class and determined the number of classes and the number of elements in each class. I’ve written out the basic conditions that I think will let me iterate over each row, over each class with the goal of copying the values from one struct into the new “class slice arrays”:

```
int x = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < total_rows - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n_classes; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < class_size[j]; k++)
        {
            data[x].value[i] =  // value at the xth position of the “class slice” array for the jth class of values in the ith row //
            x++;
        }
    }
}
```

where `data[x].value[0]` is the value I have stored for the xth sample in row i.
I guess my question is - how would you start mallocing space for arrays to store these class slices if you don’t know how many you’re even going to need (since that’s dependent on the number of rows and the number of classes)?

Example input, if this helps to make it clearer:

```
Class   Case    Case    Case    Case    Case    Case    Case    Case    Case    Case    Case    Case    Case    Case    Control Control Control Control Control Control Control Control Control Control Control Control Control Control Control Control
Obs1   0.000741628 0.00308607  0.000267431 0.001418697 0.001237904 0.000761145 0.0008281   0.002426075 0.000236698 0.004924871 0.000722752 0.003758006 0.000104813 0.000986619 0.000121803 0.000666854 0   0.000171394 0.000877993 0.002717391 0.001336501 0.000812089 0.001448743 5.28E-05    0.001944298 0.000292529 0.000469631 0.001674047 0.000651526 0.000336615
Obs2   0.102002396 0.108035127 0.015052531 0.079923731 0.020643362 0.086480609 0.017907667 0.016279315 0.076263965 0.034876124 0.187481931 0.090615572 0.037460171 0.143326961 0.029628502 0.049487575 0.020175439 0.122975405 0.019754837 0.006702899 0.014033264 0.040024363 0.076610375 0.069287599 0.098896479 0.011813681 0.293331246 0.037558052 0.303052867 0.137591517
Obs3   0.218495065 0.242891829 0.23747851  0.101306336 0.309040188 0.237477347 0.293837554 0.34351816  0.217572429 0.168651691 0.179387106 0.166516699 0.099970652 0.181003474 0.076126675 0.10244981  0.449561404 0.139257863 0.127579104 0.355797101 0.354544105 0.262855651 0.10167146  0.186068602 0.316763006 0.187466247 0.05701315  0.123825467 0.064780343 0.069847682
Obs4   0.141137543 0.090948286 0.102502388 0.013063365 0.162060849 0.166292135 0.070215996 0.063535037 0.333743609 0.131011609 0.140936687 0.150108506 0.07812762  0.230704405 0.069792935 0.120770743 0.164473684 0.448110378 0.42599534  0.074094203 0.096525097 0.157661185 0.036737518 0.213931398 0.091119285 0.438073807 0.224921728 0.187034237 0.06611442  0.086005218
Obs5   0.003594044 0.003948354 0.008137536 0.001327901 0.002161974 0.003552012 0.002760334 0.001898667 0.001420186 0.003165988 0.001011853 0.001217382 0.000314439 0.004254794 0.000213155 0.003650147 0   0.002742309 0.002633978 0   0.002524503 0.002146234 0.001751465 0.006543536 0.003941146 0.00049505  0.00435191  0.001944054 0.001303053 0.004207692
Obs6   0.000285242 2.27E-05    0   1.13E-05    0.0002964   3.62E-05    0.000138017 0.000210963 0.000662753 0   0   0   0   4.11E-05    0   0   0   0   0.000101307 0   0   0   0   5.28E-05    0.00152391  0   0   0   0   0
Obs7   0.002624223 0.001134584 0.00095511  0.000419934 0.000401011 0.001739761 0.00272583  0.002566717 0.000520735 0.002311674 0.006287944 0   6.29E-05    0.000143882 3.05E-05    0.000491366 0   0   3.38E-05    0   0.001782002 0.000957104 0.002594763 0.000527704 0.000105097 0.001192619 3.13E-05    0   0.000744602 0.000252461
Obs8   0.392777683 0.383875286 0.451499522 0.684663315 0.387394299 0.357992026 0.488406597 0.423473155 0.27267563  0.47454646  0.331020526 0.484041709 0.735955056 0.338841956 0.781699147 0.625403622 0.313596491 0.270545891 0.379259109 0.498913043 0.372438372 0.446271644 0.606698813 0.305593668 0.360535996 0.29889739  0.328710081 0.521222594 0.419924299 0.584111756
```

Comment: Start with a small array using `malloc`, and expand the array as necessary with `realloc`. Or just start with arrays of 1000 entries each. Computer memories are huge these days, and you shouldn't be shy about using it.

Comment: Ah, I was stuck in thinking that I would need a separate array for each class slice, but it would be possible (if the goal was to later perform calculations for each row comparing values between classes) to just make a three-dimensional array, e.g., double class_slice [i][j][k], which would have the kth value of the jth class in the ith row, right?

Comment: You are thinking too much in "tables" and "rows" and "columns". Think in "data". A table is just a way to display data but I still haven't understood the relationship between `Class`, `Subject` and `DataX`. Is it "A subject has N data and belongs to a class?"

Comment: I shouldn't have included subject, as it is not at all relevant to this point. The idea is that I ultimately want to perform calculations separately for each row (or Obs), and I want these calculations to be based on class (e.g., looking at the variance of Obs 1 among cases compared to the variance among controls).

Comment: data[x] refers to a struct in which I have stored class name (c_name) and value so that data[x].c_name refers to the class in the xth column, and data[x].value[y] refers to the value in xth column and yth row.

Comment: So `value` should be declared as `double *value`, initialized with `malloc`, and expanded as needed with `realloc`. `realloc` works with one-dimensional arrays, which is what `value` appears to be. Also `data` is a one-dimensional array of structures, so `malloc` and `realloc` will also work with the `data` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a struct containing a pointer to `double` and an `int` that keeps track of the number of values being stored:

```
struct data {
    int numValues;
    double *value;
};
```

If you don't know how many `data` structs you need, you declare a pointer to one, and allocate them as needed. Whenever you allocate a new `data` struct, you set the `value` to point to `NULL`. As you add values, you reallocate storage, reset the `value` pointer, and update the counter for that struct. Here is a little toy example to illustrate how it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct data {
    int numValues;
    double *value;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct data *myData;
    int numData = 0;
    int i, last;

    myData = NULL;

    ++numData;
    i = numData - 1;
    myData = realloc(myData, sizeof(*myData) * numData);

    myData[i].numValues = 0;
    myData[i].value = NULL;

    last = myData[i].numValues;
    myData[i].value = realloc(myData[i].value, sizeof(double) * (last + 1));
    myData[i].numValues += 1;
    myData[i].value[last] = 3.1415926536;

    last = myData[i].numValues;
    myData[i].value = realloc(myData[i].value, sizeof(double) * (last + 1));
    myData[i].numValues += 1;
    myData[i].value[last] = 2.7182818285;

    printf("Value [0][0]: %lf\n", myData[i].value[0]);
    printf("Value [0][1]: %lf\n", myData[i].value[1]);

    ++numData;
    i = numData - 1;
    myData = realloc(myData, sizeof(*myData) * numData);

    myData[i].numValues = 0;
    myData[i].value = NULL;

    last = myData[i].numValues;
    myData[i].value = realloc(myData[i].value, sizeof(double) * (last + 1));
    myData[i].numValues += 1;
    myData[i].value[last] = 1.6180340;

    last = myData[i].numValues;
    myData[i].value = realloc(myData[i].value, sizeof(double) * (last + 1));
    myData[i].numValues += 1;
    myData[i].value[last] = 2.99792458;

    printf("Value [1][0]: %lf\n", myData[i].value[0]);
    printf("Value [1][1]: %lf\n", myData[i].value[1]);

    /* Let's free all of the memory we allocated! */
    // first, free space allocated for values
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        free(myData[j].value);

    // next, free space allocated for structs
    free(myData);

    return 0;

}
```

### Edit

I cleaned up the code a bit and stored a couple of numbers in a second struct in an attempt to make the example a little more illustrative. I also added a few lines to free the allocated memory.

I am not exactly sure what your data is representing, but it might be useful to add a second dynamic array to the struct:

```
struct data {
    int numCase;
    int numControl;
    double *caseValue;
    double *controlValue;
};
```

Some variation on this idea would allow you to keep your "case" and "control" values separate, and you could manage the addition of new values as before.

Comment: I like this solution, but I would suggest to allocate memory in chunks and not for each value.

Comment: @kaetzacoatl This seemed relatively simple to explain and illustrate, but it's not the most efficient solution.